# JQuery toggle() stuck with two diffrent button click

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide, slidetoggle

I have a menu bar I have to hide and show on click of a register button and login button.

My HTML:

```
<div class="top">
   <ul>
      <li><a id="login" href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li><a id="register" href="#">Register</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="loginpanel">
    '<p>This is login panel</p>'
</div>

<div id="registerpanel">
    '<p>This is register panel</p>'
</div>

<div class="menu">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I have to hide the Menu on login and register click but when I click on regular interval the `toggle()` function not work properly like when I click on login button it will hide but when click on register link the menu will appear

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("a#login").click(function () {    
        $(".menu").toggle();
        $("#loginpanel").slideToggle();  
        return false;
    });
    $("a#register").click(function () {
        $(".menu").toggle();
        $("#registerpanel").slideToggle();   
        return false;   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/CZC35/ - works for me. I removed the 'a' from $('a#register') and $('a#login') selectors and removed references to registerpanel because it is not in your markup. Also you had an extra ending li tag and class="top was missing a final "

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to tell exactly what do you want. I am totally confused. All the answerers will want to know that.

Comment: i have to hide the menu bar when login/register panel open.. and show the menu bar when the login/register panel close toggle is work fine but problem occurs when a user open the login panel and click on the register button without closing the login panel the menu bar will not hide just check this[link]http://jsfiddle.net/e7SKp/12/

you have to click on login button
thereafter click  on register button

might be you understand what problem occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanx to @[Dipesh
>   Parmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540328/dipesh-parmar) who help
>   me to short out my problem...

**MY HTML CODE**

```
<div class="top">
<ul>
<li><a id="login" href="#">Login</a></li>
<li><a id="register" href="#">Register</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="loginpanel">
    '<p>This is login panel</p>'
</div>

<div id="registerpanel">
    '<p>This is register panel</p>'
</div>

<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#loginpanel
{
    display:none;
}


#registerpanel
{
    display:none;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
   $("a#login").click(function ()
    {
        if($('#loginpanel').is(':visible')) {
            $('.menu').show();
        } else {
            $('.menu').hide();
        }
        $("#loginpanel").stop().slideToggle();  
        $("#registerpanel").hide();
    });

    $("a#register").click(function ()
    {
        if($('#registerpanel').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.menu').hide();
        } else {
            $('.menu').show();
        }
        $("#registerpanel").stop().slideToggle();
        $("#loginpanel").hide();        
    });



$("a#login").click(function ()
{
    $("#loginpanel").stop().slideToggle('fast',function(){
        if($('#loginpanel').is(':visible')) {
            $('.menu').show();
        } else {
            $('.menu').hide();
        }
    });
    $("#registerpanel").hide();
});

    $("a#register").click(function ()
    {
        $("#registerpanel").stop().slideToggle('fast',function(){
            if($('#registerpanel').is(':hidden')) {
                $('.menu').hide();
            } else {
                $('.menu').show();
            }
        });
        $("#loginpanel").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on `when i click on regular interval the toggle() function not work properly` this line you are firing multiple click event so your code for toggle gets stucked

So you need way to tell DOM to stop what its doing and start over again.

Also you have extra `li`.. at `<li><a id="login" href="#">Login</a></li></li>` if its typo then ignore.

So use `.stop()`

```
$("a#login").click(function ()
{
    $(".menu").stop().hide();
    $("#loginpanel").stop().slideToggle();     
    return false;
});

$("a#register").click(function ()
{
    $(".menu").stop().show();
    $("#registerpanel").stop().slideToggle();  
    return false;   
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7SKp/1/)

Comment: lil bit better to use of '$(".menu").stop().toggle();' but jquery till like if the menu is hide on login click but without closing the login panle I click on register button the menu is visble in register panel and if i used '$(".menu").stop().hide();' the links are disapper when i close the login panel

Comment: @ArunMaddheshia Yes i got it...see my previous comment for `.stop().toggle()`  http://jsfiddle.net/e7SKp/2/

Comment: don't be angry dude.. actually I just want when i click on login button the menu will hide/show and login panel show/hide and when i click on register button menu will hide/show and register panel will be show/hide but the problem is that when i click on login button the menu will hide and login panel open on this point when i click on register button the register panel is visible but the menu will not hide it will conflict just check it again...[/link]http://jsfiddle.net/e7SKp/2/

Comment: it need to improve more just click on login button and then click the register button you will see the menu will not hide .

Comment: one little bit problem is this function not work with 'slideToggler();'

Comment: @ArunMaddheshia let me try few alternative for that...wait a second.

Comment: thanx for your feedback but I short out just putting the if condition before the ' $("#loginpanel").slideToggle();'

Comment: @ArunMaddheshia okay here is demo you can do this by adding callback function.....http://jsfiddle.net/e7SKp/28/

Answer (score 0):

In your first line you have an error

```
<div class="top>
```

Complete the class with quote and it will work for you

```
<div class="top">
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/H5asM/) you wanted. You did not close the last function in your script.

Comment: I dont see any change in behaviour. Can you tell what does it do?